# Column not reaching its desired postion

Tags: html, css

Having an issue where i have two columns a left and right that will not go the 100% to the bottom where it should meet with the about dealer section. I have a left column and a center column and a right column. The center is the one that is filled with content and the right and left column should flow along with it without any content in it.

I have researched this for the last two day and have tried a ton of different things found on stack overflow and other sites, the big difference was setting the `html, body{ height: 100%}` to 100% along with using the `vh` on the columns. this works somewhat and am looking for a little help on what I'm doing wrong

I can't figure out why it only goes down 740px and stops.

I can post all the code but there is a lot of it so for now ill just give the parts I'm talking about.

If there is more information/code needed please let me know so i can present it.

Here is the site hosted for viewing [Site Here](http://juicycougarmeat.com/problem/frontDoor.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home Page</title>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="frontDoor.css"/>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="header">

    <div class="leftColumn"></div>

        <div class="centerBox">
            <div class="slideShow">
                Slide Show
            </div>
            <div class="autoSearch">
                auto Search
            </div>
            <div class="recList">
                <span><b>Recent</b></span>Listings
            </div>

            <div class="recImg">
                <img src="images/honda.png" alt="car" width="200" />
                <img src="images/honda.png" alt="car" width="200"/>
                <img src="images/honda.png" alt="car" width="200"/>
        <img src="images/honda.png" alt="car" width="200"/>                 
            </div>

            <div class="srchSell">

                <div class="srchBut">
                    <button class="button but1">SEARCH</button>
                </div>

                <div class="sellBut">
                    <button class="button but2">SELL</button>                   
                </div>                      
            </div>

            <div class="recBlog">
                <div class="blogImg">
                    <img src="images/honda.png" alt="car" width="200"/>
                </div>
                <div class="blogImg">
                    <img src="images/honda.png" alt="car" width="200"/>
                </div>
                <div class="blogImg">
                    <img src="images/honda.png" alt="car" width="200"/>
                </div>                  
            </div>

            <div class="autoNews">
            Auto news
                <hr class="style-six">
                <div class="news">
                    <img src="images/honda.png" alt="car" width="150" />
                </div>
                <div class="news">
                    <img src="images/honda.png" alt="car" width="150" />
                </div>                  
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="rightColumn"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Here is the CSS

```
html {height: 100%;}
body{
   background-color: #222222;
   font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
}
.wrapper {
   margin: 0 auto; 
   width: 960px;/*1688px*/
   height: 100%;
   background-color:#b3ffb3; 
}
.rightColumn{
  float: left;
  width: 70px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px sold gray;
  background-color:#fff;
}
/* This is the center column */
.centerBox{
  float:left;
  width: 820px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px sold gray;
  background-color:#fff;
  overflow: hidden;
```

}

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Please make your question clearer.

Comment: Updates it, hope it makes a little more sense.

Comment: See @Johannes answer, but also I'd recommend you try using display:block; display:inline-block; display:table and display:table-cell; I can see how using floats can be convinient for beginners, but in general on most cases it is not the best method.

Comment: Thank you I'll look more into that, kinda felt like it wasn't the best way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to wrap the three columns in a container DIV (`.wrap_3` in my snippet below) and apply `display: flex` and `height: 100%` to that container. Also `html` and `body` need `height: 100%` for that height setting to work.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #222222;
  font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
  /*1688px*/
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #b3ffb3;
}

.wrap_3 {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.leftColumn {
  width: 70px;
  border: 1px sold gray;
  background-color: #fb7;
}

.rightColumn {
  width: 70px;
  border: 1px sold gray;
  background-color: #b8f;
}

.centerBox {
  width: 820px;
  border: 1px sold gray;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap_3">
  <div class="leftColumn"></div>

  <div class="centerBox">
    <div class="slideShow">
      Slide Show
    </div>
    <div class="autoSearch">
      auto Search
    </div>
    <div class="recList">
      <span><b>Recent</b></span>Listings
    </div>

    <div class="recImg">
      <img src="images/honda.png" alt="car" width="200" />
      <img src="images/honda.png" alt="car" width="200" />
      <img src="images/honda.png" alt="car" width="200" />
      <img src="images/honda.png" alt="car" width="200" />
    </div>

    <div class="srchSell">

      <div class="srchBut">
        <button class="button but1">SEARCH</button>
      </div>

      <div class="sellBut">
        <button class="button but2">SELL</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="recBlog">
      <div class="blogImg">
        <img src="images/honda.png" alt="car" width="200" />
      </div>
      <div class="blogImg">
        <img src="images/honda.png" alt="car" width="200" />
      </div>
      <div class="blogImg">
        <img src="images/honda.png" alt="car" width="200" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="autoNews">
      Auto news
      <hr class="style-six">
      <div class="news">
        <img src="images/honda.png" alt="car" width="150" />
      </div>
      <div class="news">
        <img src="images/honda.png" alt="car" width="150" />
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="rightColumn"></div>
</div>
```